# Retrieving specific directories using os.walk()

Tags: python, os.walk

I have a set of jobs (`job1`, `job2` etc) that runs every hour and after they are completed generate folders (`session1`, `session2` etc) which contains the log files. Due to storage limitation, I need a script that can delete the session directories older than a set time limit but also want to specify that it must keeps a specified number of session directories e.g keep the latest 2 sessions, even if they are older than set time limit.

How can I achieve this using python `os.walk()`? I want to return a list of session dirs to delete `sessions_to_delete = []`

```
/root    
    /job1             (runs every one hour)    
        /session1
            /*log
        /session2
        /session3
    /job2
        /session1
        /session2
```

Comment: To sort candidates you may use `os.stat`.

Comment: Latest 2 sessions per job?

Comment: Yes. Latest 2 for all jobs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, it is probably easier to list all directories with [`glob.glob()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html), to match your hierarchy pattern. You can use [`os.path.getctime()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.getctime) to get a timestamp for each directory to sort and filter by

```
from glob import glob
import os.path
import time

def find_sessions_to_delete(cutoff):
    # produce a list of (timestamp, path) tuples for each session directory
    session_dirs = [(os.path.getctime(p), p) for p in glob('/root/job*/session*')]
    session_dirs.sort(reverse=True)  # sort from newest to oldest
    # remove first two elements, they are kept regardless
    session_dirs = session_dirs[2:]
    # return a list of paths whose ctime lies before the cutoff time
    return [p for t, p in session_dirs if t <= cutoff]

cutoff = time.time() - (7 * 86400)  # 7 days ago
sessions_to_delete = find_sessions_to_delete(cutoff)
```

I included a sample cutoff date at 7 days ago, calculated from [`time.time()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.time), which returns an integer value, expressing the number of seconds passed since the 1st of January 1970 (the UNIX epoch).

If you needed to do this *per job directory*, do the same work *per such directory* and merge the resulting lists:

```
def find_sessions_to_delete(cutoff):
    to_delete = []

    # process each jobdir separately
    for jobdir in glob('/root/job*'):
        # produce a list of (timestamp, path) tuples for each session directory
        session_dirs = [(os.path.getctime(p), p)
                        for p in glob(os.path.join(jobdir, 'session*'))]
        session_dirs.sort(reverse=True)  # sort from newest to oldest
        # remove first two elements, they are kept regardless
        session_dirs = session_dirs[2:]
        # Add list of paths whose ctime lies before the cutoff time
        to_delete.extend(p for t, p in session_dirs if t <= cutoff)

    return to_delete
```

Comment: I want to keep the latest two session from each job...if there is only 1 session, keep that one.. dont remove anythin?

Comment: @Emmanuel: then you'd use the same techique, only once per job directory and merge the lists. I'll add a version for that.

Comment: Thank you Martijn! this solved my problem and it's very easy to understand what the code is doing

Comment: Why use to_delete.extend() and not to_delete.append()?

Comment: @Emmanuel: because we have more than one item to add to the list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use os.path.getatime(path) or os.path.getmtime(path) to figure out how "old" is a folder and then do what you need to do with it...
Here the basic info about the os.path module https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#module-os.path

one approach to solve your problem could be this one:

```
import os
import time

for folder in list_of_folders:
    if time.time() - os.path.getmtime(folder) > time_limit:
        delete_folder(folder)
```

if you build up the list_of_folders using append() then you can save the last two folders by changing the for loop easily like this.

```
for folder in list_of_folders[:-2]:
```